# What are the equivalent of these functions in gtk2Hs when migrating from gtk2 to gtk3

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2hs

I'm converting a Haskell program written with Gtk2Hs [gtk2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.15.0) to Gtk2Hs [gtk3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0) and I'm looking the equivalent function of Gtk2Hs [gtk2](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.15.0) for:

`onActivateLeaf` to catch the activation of a menu item.

`onExpose` to draw in a widget.

`onClicked` to catch the clicked event of a button.

`onDestroy` to catch the destroy event of a Widget.

I had a look at these function in the documentation but they are used to **send** a signal not to **catch** one.

[`menuItemActivate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-MenuItem.html#v:menuItemActivate) [`buttonClicked`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Buttons-Button.html#v:buttonClicked) [`widgetDestroy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:widgetDestroy)

**Can you tell me the right way to catch event for widget with the Gtk2Hs gtk3 API ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I would start by checking these:

- [`menuItemActivated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-MenuItem.html#v:menuItemActivated)
- [`draw`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:draw)
- [`buttonActivated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Buttons-Button.html#v:buttonActivated)
- [`destroyEvent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.15.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:destroyEvent)

The `on` prefixes have been done away with in favor of a single function named [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib-0.13.6.0/docs/System-Glib-Signals.html#v:on).

Comment: That's it. Perfect !